# Can an optimizer assume a floating point is not NaN?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Compilers are allowed to make several assumptions that would lead to undefined behaviour (such as assuming addition doesn't overflow). May they make such an assumption with regards to floating point NaN?

For example:

```
double a = some_calc();
double b = a;
if( a == b )
  do_something();
```

Can the optimizer remove the conditional statement and assume that it is always true? Or is it bound to the platform floating point rules (IEEE) and forced to do the check in case the value is NaN?

That is, can the compiler optimize based on the assumption that a double does not contain NaN? As the C++ standard doesn't say a lot about how floating point actually works on the platform, I'm not clear if this is actually fully specified.

Comment: If the implementation documents itself as supporting NaNs, then it has to support NaNs. The optimizer is part of the implementation. Is that enough information? ;-)

Comment: That is, could the implementation define NaN such to allow the above optimization. The standard does have an `isnan` function, so there'd be no loss of functionality.

Comment: I don't think the C++ standard requires that `NaN != NaN`, where `NaN` is a quiet NaN. If I'm right, then a C++ implementation could define its own not-a-numbers such that `NaN == NaN`, and then the optimization would be valid. The implementation wouldn't support *IEEE* NaNs. If I'm wrong, and it's required by C++ that `NaN != NaN`, then the optimizer can't treat `operator==(double,double)` the way it treats `operator==(int,int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Or is it bound to the platform floating point rules (IEEE)*

Not necessarily, if the implementation uses IEEE 754 floating point numbers, `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` is set to true.

> *and forced to do the check in case the value is NaN?*

If the implementation *does* use IEEE 754, the result of arithmetic operations must match IEEE floating point rules, but as far as comparison goes, it can be optimised. If the body of `some_calc` is available for the analysis by the compiler in the same translation unit (or during link-time code generation) *and* it can conclude that it never returns NaN (i.e. returns a constant), it can be optimised, as the semantics of the code don't change.

Comment: So the decision would hinge on whether the compiler can definitively know whether `some_calc` can return NaN. If it can't know with 100% certainty it would have to do the comparison (or do a nan check if that might be faster).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, yes, this is true of all optimisations. If the body of the function is opaque to the compiler, it can't assume anything (the function can return any value and also have side effects)

Comment: However, some compilers have optimizer flags so the user can tell them, "I don't care about NaNs." With such a flag, the compiler would then ignore the possibility of NaNs here.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, well, some compilers also have flags to ignore accurately reproducing IEEE semantics, so there's that. :)